# How to plan with STOMP on Humble?

Tags: ros-humble, motion-planners, moveit2

Duplicate of (https://github.com/orgs/ros-planning/discussions/2737)
I am looking for an up-to-date tutorial on planning with the STOMP planning algorithm. I am using ros `Humble` on `Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS`. However, when I install moveit2 from binary `sudo apt-get install ros-humble-moveit*`, I encounter exceptions that `stomp_moveit/StompPlanner` is unknown, among others.

I also tried to install moveit2 from the source, but I noticed that STOMP is not present in the `moveit_planners` directory on Humble branch since the migration commit `e3539be58a1f972e6deba4c61dbfb46fecb2b3d5` ([PR](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/pull/2158)) is only available on the main branch. Moreover, the repo [stomp_moveit](https://github.com/ros-planning/stomp_moveit) is already marked as a public archive, and I believe it was a work in progress before it was archived.

Can someone please provide a brief tutorial on how to set up the environment for the planner STOMP?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, STOMP is included in Iron, but not in Humble

Comment: Is it possible to migrate STOMP also to Humble branch? Resp, do you think the process will be challenging?

Comment: anyway, thanks for the response

Comment: I asked that same question in MoveIt's github, but with no response:

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/issues/2550

My gut feeling is that it shouldn't be super hard, but in my (short) experience with MoveIt, things are always harder than the look.